# how can I cover [MM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss:mmm(AM/PM)] to unix timestamp?

Tags: sql, unix-timestamp

I want to convert the following date format to "May 13 2020 12:00:00:000AM" to UNIX formatted timestamps in milliseconds. Can you please advice on doing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place? It's much better to work with real `timestamp` values directly, not with some integer values.